# Is there a way to evaluate promise in nodejs without resuming debugger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

If I type debugger and I want to check something. But call to that function returns a promise, then i am stuck.

For example:

I typed debugger and it stopped.

```
function test(db) {
    debugger;
    // here i want to see something
    var a = .....;
}
```

But if I type

```
let d = db.User.create();
```

I'll get

```
Promise { pending }
```

now there is no recourse. I can't simply evaluate promise. Kinda make whole debugger less useful.

This would have been no problem, if it was synchronous, I'd have been able to jump in mid program, check out few things and modify program to my liking then run rest of the program.

Comment: Well if the promise does not have a result yet, you cannot evaluate it. You need to let the code resume to fulfill the promise.

Comment: What is  `d`? Where are yo calling `test`?

Comment: suppose test is called somewhere in program flow, point is debugger gets called. Then in console you type `db.User.Create()` which returns a promise.

Comment: Well, no, you cannot get an asynchronous result from anything while being paused at a breakpoint.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_experimental_repl_await

Comment: @MuhammadUmer does it work for you when 'debugger;' is set? For me it doesn't

Comment: start node with that flag, make sure version is > 10.xyz whatever it says there... paste this `p  = new Promise((r,e)=> r(3),()=>3)
result = await p;
console.log(result)` I get 3 in result

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, it works in `node repl`. But your question is about `debugger;`. When the code is stopped on a breakpoint then async code doesn't work - `Promise {<pending>}` is returned.

Comment: chrome supports async debugging, so if you debug using chrome dev tools and --inspect flag on nodejs you can do async debugging

Comment: using async/await syntax should be helpful.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, do you mean that your example now works with the latest dev tools and with the --inspect flag in nodejs? I'm trying to debug something similar like you did in your question and I can't. Did you enable something?

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65018201/1319799 (in nodejs top level works if you are using "module" type and version is > 13.3)

Answer (score 3):

Probably in order to understand why promises can't be resolved while debugger is paused, you need to understand how **Event Loop** works. There are plenty of resources about it so no need to explain it here.

When you pause a **Debugger**, **Event Loop** gets paused too. And everything asynchronous is scheduled and handled in **Event Loop**.

Possible ways to resolve promise in debugger:

- Somehow execute promise synchronously by pooling it manually. But as far as I checked, there is no way to do that. **V8** doesn't give us that level of control. But maybe it can be achieved by writing **Native Addon**. Perhaps a function that accepts a promise and resolves it using **V8**'s internals synchronously.
- Create a new **Web Worker** or another process and execute the promise there. But you'd have to serialize the data and possibly recreate the state. Though it won't work anyways since creating and passing messages to new "thread" is asynchronous, so...

Unfortunately at the moment best and simplest ways I am aware of are:

1. Print current state and use it to construct and execute code outside of the debugger.
2. Assign result to a variable and **continue(F5)** debugger, so that your promise can be resolved. After use it as you'd like:

```
db.User.create().then(x => global.a = x);
// use global.a as you'd like:
console.log(global.a);
```

Comment: "*Somehow execute promise synchronously by pooling it manually*" - this makes no sense. A promise cannot be "executed". A promise doesn't know from where it gets resolved. You need to continue the entire process so that *the code that will resolve the promise* can run.

Comment: @Bergi yes there currently is no way to achieve that because v8 doesnt provide such api and implementation. That is what I wrote. What you are saying is the way it is now. By creating addon we could possibly implement such functionality, if NApi provides enough low level control.

Comment: No, what I'm trying to say is that the functionality itself doesn't make sense. There can be no such addon. "*A function that accepts a promise and resolves it*" can easily be created, but it cannot resolve it with the value that the program would have produced. The only way to get the value that the OP wants is to resume the program.

Comment: Functionality iteself doesn't make sense? how so? I am talking conceptually about possible solutions, not taking into account available api and implementation detail since I am not familiar with those.

Comment: And I am saying that it is not even conceptually possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger at the either event of the promise being resolved or rejected.

```
function test(db) {

   let d = db.User.create(); 

   d.then((result) => {
      debugger;
      ...
   },
   (e) => {
      debugger;
      ...
   })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome not too long ago launched `async` debugging in their Chrome Devtools. You need to enable the flag in chrome to use it for now.

Check out this nice article here - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

Comment: i think it's also being added to nodejs

Comment: Just in nodejs REPL it works. It doesn't work if 'debugger' is set in the script

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://gist.github.com/martinheidegger/4c2b7908005f65f9a53b25d5fec65f63
check debug-promise.js  module

```
'use strict'

var debug = require('./debug-promise')

debug.wrap(() => new Promise(() => {})).then(() => console.log('a executed'))
debug.wrap(() => Promise.resolve('x')).then(() => console.log('b executed'))


//
// This will output something like:
//
//   b executed
//   1 Promise is still unfullfilled!
//   --- (V347P-M6K) ---
//     at Object.<anonymous> (/debug-test2.js:5:7)
//     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
//     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
//   
//     CODE
//       () => new Promise(() => {})
//   
//   ---
//
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const foo = async(db)=>{//just be sure that you are in async for this one

try{

let d = await db.User.create(); 
//now d is the result
}catch (err) {console.log(err)}
```

Or more basically

```
 db.User.create().then((data)=>console.log('user created',data))
                 .catch(err=>console.log('err'));
```

That's how you resolve promises. Don't forget to add the catch or you will have some trouble.