# Top-level await does not work with node 14.13.-

Tags: javascript, node.js, top-level-await

I have node 14.13.0, and even with `--harmony-top-level-await`, top-level await is not working.

```
$ cat i.js
const l = await Promise.new(r => r("foo"))
console.log(l)

$ node -v
v14.13.0

$ node --harmony-top-level-await i.js
/Users/karel/i.js:1
const l = await Promise.new(r => r("foo"))
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:791:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Top-level `await` only works with ESM modules (JavaScript's own module format), not with Node.js's default CommonJS modules. From your stack trace, you're using CommonJS modules.

You need to put `"type": "module"` in `package.json` or use `.mjs` as the file extension (I recommend using the setting).

For instance, with this `package.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

and this `main.js`:

```js
const x = await Promise.resolve(42);
console.log(x);
```

`node main.js` shows 42.

---

Side note: You don't need `--harmony-top-level-await` with v14.13.0. Top-level await is enabled by default in that version (it was enabled in [v14.8.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.8.0/)).

Comment: FWIW, I go into using ESM with Node.js, and separate go into top-level `await`, in some detail in Chapters 13 and 19 of my new(ish) book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

T.J. Crowder answer is right, but I recommend changing all the `.js` to `.mjs`

For example, if you are working with NextJS like me, you will see a problem that files in the `.next` directory use CommonJS (`.next` is generated using `npx next build`) and their extensions are `js` so it raises an error when the `.next` files use `require()`