# Top level await not working in Node JS 14.15.3

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am on running Node version 14.15.3

`Welcome to Node.js v14.15.3.`

I thought it was cool that you could use `await` now in top level scripts, so I tried it. To not my surprise, it didn't work.

```
const myfunc = async () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {res()},1000)
    })
}
await myfunc();
```

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Not sure what else to say. It just doesn't work.. Did it break? Did it ever really work?

Comment: Deno supports top-level await, but as far as I know, Node doesn't

Comment: https://itnext.io/node-js-script-writers-top-level-async-await-now-available-a1e86566d5f6

Comment: Ah, my bad then

Comment: Are you using commonjs or es6 modules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top-level await does not work with node 14.13.-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018150/top-level-await-does-not-work-with-node-14-13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top-level await works within ECMAScript modules. By default, NodeJS doesn't use these, and instead, it uses CommonJS modules. There are a few ways to enable ES6 modules in your node project though as outlined [here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system):

> Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to node as the initial input, or when referenced by import statements within ES module code:
>
> - Files ending in .mjs.
> - Files ending in .js when the nearest parent package.json file contains a top-level field "type" with a value of "module".
> - Strings passed in as an argument to --eval or --print, or piped to node via STDIN, with the flag --input-type=module

If you use one of the above approaches to enable ES6 modules within your project, then you'll be able to use top-level await:

**script.mjs** (note the .mjs):

```js
const myfunc = async () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {res("Hello")}, 1000)
  })
}
console.log(await myfunc()); // logs "Hello" after ~1s
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 solutions.

First. Change extension to .ejs

Second. You need to add type in package.json

```
   "type": "module"
```