# Top level await not working in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-modules, top-level-await

I am rather confused as I have read that top level await is supported in ESM but when I try it out in a html file it does not work?

Were I found that is says:
[Top-level await does not work with node 14.13.-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018150/top-level-await-does-not-work-with-node-14-13)
"Top-level await only works with ESM modules"

Is top level await supported in ESM and if how can I use it.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'hello1';
await pause(2000); // is this possible if so how
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'hello2';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's supported in ESM - ES6 modules. It's *not* supported in plain script tags.

```html
<script>
await Promise.resolve();
</script>
```

You need to specify that the script is a module for it to work.

```html
<script type="module">
await Promise.resolve();
console.log('finished successfully');
</script>
```

(Also make sure that you're running this in a supported environment - older environments may not support top-level await)